# How to make an animation of "cancel" button when touch the UITextField

Tags: ios, animation, uitextfield

I am now creating an App that has a browser like Safari:
There is a UITextField(left side) and UISearchBar(right side) inserted into the UINavigationBar on the top of the view.
I am wondering if there is a way to add an animation on a "Cancel" button at the time it appears when user touches the UITextField. 
 
The animation is just like it is on the Safari: when User touches the UITextField, the "Cancel" button comes from right outside of the window while the UISearchBar is fading.
Note that I am initializing the "Cancel" button by UIBarbuttonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel).
Any help would be appreciated.

Update: 
Finally I found the anwser by myself. It seems that you cannot assign a specific position where UIBarButtonItem shows up or hide. So one possible way to solve this problem is to customize a UIButton just looks like the UIBarButtonItem, here is the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ......
    CGSize backgroundStretchPoints = {4, 2};
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarDefaultButton.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:backgroundStretchPoints.width
                                                                                               topCapHeight:backgroundStretchPoints.height];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(330, 23, 80, 30); // initialize the button outside the window
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [navigationBar addSubview: button];
    .......
}
```

and when you click the UITextField(i.e.), the cancel button will slide into the window:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        button.frame = CGRectMake(232, 23, 80, 30);  // here is the position button will slide into window with animation
    }];
```

}